# PowerShell XML Parsing in 1.0 and 2.0

Tags: xml, powershell, service, server

I'm trying to run the below script on around 200 servers. It's job is quite simple, it's meant to pull a list of services that have the Start Mode Automatic, and then search them against an XML document, 247_Config.xml. The XML document is the configuration document for a bit of monitoring software we use. Any services it doesn't find in the document, it writes out so we can add them.

This works beautifully on our newer 2012 servers, but on the old 2003 and some of the SBS servers, it doesn't parse the XML properly. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

```
$Services = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | Where-Object { $_.StartMode -eq 'Auto'} | Select 'Name','DisplayName'
[xml]$DATA=GET-CONTENT "..\247_Config.xml"
$AMAServices = $DATA.Checks.WinServiceCheck.ServiceName
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Output = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$datatest = @()

foreach ( $jeff in $AMAServices ){ $datatest = $datatest += $jeff.'#cdata-section' }
foreach ( $service in $Services) { $Output = $Output += $service.DisplayName -join "'n" }

foreach ( $item in $datatest )
{
    for ( $item2=0; $item2 -lt $Output.Count; $item2++ )
    {
        $index = $Output[$item2]
        If ( $item -like $index ){ $Output.Remove($index)}
    }
}

#### EXCLUSIONS ####
for ($ex=0; $ex -lt $Output.Count; $ex++)
{
If( $Output[$ex] -contains "ShellHWDetection" -or
$Output[$ex] -contains "McTaskManager" -or
$Output[$ex] -contains "Advanced Monitoring Agent"
)
{ $Output.Remove($Output[$ex]) }
}

#### OUTPUT ####
if ($Output.Count -ne 0)
{
for ($a=0; $a -lt $Output.Count; $a++){ Write-Host $Output[$a] }
Exit 1010
}
Else
{
Write-Host "All services being checked."
Exit 0
}
```

Sam.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how the XML isn't parsed properly? What is the output?

Comment: What happens when you run just this line `[xml]$DATA=GET-CONTENT "..\247_Config.xml"` on one of those older systems?  If it worked, try the next line and see what happens `$DATA.Checks.WinServiceCheck.ServiceName` I ran a similar line on a PowerShell 2.0 system and that syntax worked perfectly.

Comment: This is where the parsing beaks down. I've used the ISE debugger to break it at these points. The $DATA variable ends up with "#Document" inside it. The `$DATA.Checks.WinServiceCheck.ServiceName` line then comes up empty.

Comment: Fixed it! I changed the `$AMAServices = $DATA.Checks.WinServiceCheck.ServiceName` line to `$AMAServices = $DATA.SelectNodes("//checks/WinServiceCheck/servicename")` and it came back to life. Thank you all for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the

```
$AMAServices = $DATA.Checks.WinServiceCheck.ServiceName
```

line to

```
$AMAServices = $DATA.SelectNodes("//checks/WinServiceCheck/servicename")
```

This parsed correctly. Tested on all version of PowerShell.